Typo3 Backend Debugging (Extbase)
I try to debug some things from a backend module (ActionController / Repository classes) using
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(). Unfortunately this has no effect. I remember that normally there was a panel in the backend showing the data, but in my case this doesn't appear. I enabled the debug preset in the configuration. Does anyone have suggestions?
Thanks
Sebastian

The Backend Module Template API will probably swallow the output because it's not part of your proper response object.
Generally, if possible, I would advise you to use Xdebug for inspect data rather than "cowboy"-debugging.
Another option would be that you can use the parameters plainText and return of var_dump(), so that you can pipe through the output of that call to some ->assign() of your template. Or, you may want to pass through the data you want to inspect/debug to your template and use <f:debug> there.

As @Garvin Hicking mentioned, xdebug is super helpful, especially in the backend. But if you can't or don't want to run xdebug, just try putting a die() after your debug.

    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($whatEver);
    die();

